# AC current on relay causes Pi Pico to reboot continuously

Tags: resistors, solid-state-relay, rp2040, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm working on a project that involves a Raspberry Pi Pico driving two 4-channel relay modules. With no power supplied to the modules, everything works great - they open and close as designed for my application. One of the two modules is driving four arrays of 12 V LEDs using a 12 V DC battery; no issues there.

The second relay module is driving one of four sets of EL wire, which use a 2xAA battery pack with a 3 V AC transformer inside.

Most of the time, the Pi will immediately reboot if the power source for the EL Wire is at all connected to the second relay, though it sometimes manages to activate one or two of the relays on the module before doing so.

I have a feeling I need to isolate that AC power somehow, but I'm not sure what needs to happen. I understand they're already supposed to be opto-isolated.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it.

Here's the hardware I purchased:

Relay - [https://amazon.com/dp/B07DN8DTRW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DN8DTRW)

EL Wire - [https://amazon.com/gp/product/B08THDC2CX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08THDC2CX)

Here's what the EL pack looks like inside, and what I did to it to make it able to be powered constantly:

https://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2018-04/09_hacking_el-wire_inverter_on_off_switch

Pin definitions in the code:

```python
self.happy_button = Pin(10, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
self.sad_button = Pin(11, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
self.scared_button = Pin(12, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)
self.thinking_button = Pin(13, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_DOWN)

self.happy_relay = LowRelay(2, Pin.OUT) # just subclassed to reverse off/on
self.sad_relay = LowRelay(3, Pin.OUT)
self.scared_relay = LowRelay(4, Pin.OUT)
self.thinking_relay = LowRelay(5, Pin.OUT)
self.group1_relay = LowRelay(6, Pin.OUT)
self.group2_relay = LowRelay(7, Pin.OUT)
self.group3_relay = LowRelay(8, Pin.OUT)
self.rgb_relay = LowRelay(9, Pin.OUT)
```

Finally, here's my schematic:

[image: Ariel Schematic]

**Edit:**
With everyone's advice, I've altered the schematic a good bit.  I've moved all AC power to another pot to avoid EMI, and the secondary relay module now only provides power to the appropriate inverter, which provides power to one of the four strands of EL wire.  This means that I'll have to put all four DC/AC inverters in the pot, but I can't see a good way around that without switch the AC power, and I don't currently have any MOSFETs or other relay modules to work with.  I've moved the 5 V power for the relays to pin 40, and I'll add bypass caps between pin 40 (VBUS) and pin 38 (ground), as well as pin 36 (3.3V) and 38 (GND) as soon as I can get them.  Here's the updated schematic.  If anyone can confirm I've covered all the bases that would be fantastic! Thanks, everyone. :)

[image]

**Edit 2:**
Just thought I'd post an update on this project.  Moving the AC power to another pot away from the Pico did the trick.  Everything worked perfectly (with the exception of EL wire being too dim under stage lights), and the costume was a big hit.  Thank you all for your help!

[image: The final product]

Comment: Welcome! Connect your oscilloscope to Vcc and capture said restart. How does it look?

Comment: All your loads are DC and do not require isolation. Why use relays instead of MOSFETs?

Comment: Do you not have any bypass capacitors on the power supplies? Why do you seem to be using 5V relays from 3.3V logic signals? And what current does the relay pack need?

Comment: Thanks for your replies!  
@winny: I unfortunately don't have an oscilloscope, so I've no idea.

Comment: @bobflux: The LED loads would have been prime candidates for that had I been more familiar with MOSFETs.  I'll probably alter my design.  The EL wire loads are AC, however... would those loads also work with mosfets?

Comment: @PStechPaul: I do not have any bypass capacitors in place.  Where would that go? Relay ground to EL wire ground?  The relay runs on 5v and can trigger via 3v.  It's switching the relays from GPIO without issues, but as soon as that AC from the EL pack is connected the pico reboots.

Comment: The EL wires use AC, generated by the small inverters "EL packs". You can use a MOSFET to switch the DC supply to the inverters. In fact you could do that with the relays too, it could solve your problem, because the DC side should have little noise, while the AC side is high frequency AC that can leak through the relay's capacitance.

Comment: @bobflux: That's the only solution I've been coming across online as well - use the relay or a MOSFET to switch on/off the inverter power.  I've got four different EL wires to power, and was hoping that I could get away with including just a single power pack.  I think I can still do that by including all four inverters and use the relay to control which one gets the power from 2xAA.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, nice schematic! Post a link to the relays you actually used, a link to a sales outlet such as azon generally useless. The reason I ask it appears the relay coils are not isolated. If you can switch the negative side implementing MOSFETs will be easy and straightforward.

Comment: I would suggest bypass capacitors of 100-470 nF from 3V3 to GND as well as Vcc (5V?) to GND.

Comment: Sorry, you need an oscilloscope to develop electronics. Without it, it’s guesswork. My best guess you be you lack decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I really appreciate it!  I've updated the post with new schematics.  If anyone can confirm I've covered all the bases that would be fantastic. :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use VBUS (pin 40) in place of VSYS (pin 39), because there is a diode between these pins.
And add a decoupling capacitor (perhaps a supercapacitor 6V), because you are driving relays with a high current supply need (~100 mA ?)
Perhaps also insert a diode between VBUS and the VCC supply of relays boards.
I also should use pin 38 preferably as GND for relays boards in place of pin8 and pin13.
More nearest of the "input" power supply pins ...

[pico datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/pico-datasheet.pdf).

[image]

Here is what I should do

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've updated the schematics based on your comments and others'.  If you can confirm I've covered the bases I'd really appreciate it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hope that now all is working without any flaws ... Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that you are switching the EL wire itself with the relays. And you don't mention how you power the EL power supply, i.e. batteries or the 3.3V.

Contrary to what you may assume, the EL power supply itself works on 3V DC, but it outputs high voltage at high frequency. Maybe 100 volts AC at few kilohertz. And the EL wire itself is a highly capacitive load.

It is likely that the intended operation of the EL supply is not to abruptly disconnect and reconnect the EL supply output to EL lights. Or to even keep it turned on without a connected load.

The disconnection of EL wire with a relay may cause a spark between relay contacts and that is quite a strong source of electromagnetic interference. The connection of EL wire may cause a large current spike needed to charge the capacitive EL wire, and high currents flowing in a loop of wire is again a transmitting antenna for electromagnetic interference. And it is unknown how the EL supply behaves with no load, the output voltage may be much higher and it could arc over the open relay contacts, or capacitively couple the high voltage high frequency waveform to nearby wiring.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. It corroborates a lot of what I’m surmising from deeper digging.  Yes - I was using the intended 2xAA power supply for the EL wire rather than the 3.3v pin on the pico. I have now seen that the EL power supply is not recommended to operate without at least 3” of wire at all times, and I *almost* put an EMI tag on this post because I guessed that might be the issue.  I’ll switch to toggling the on/off button for the EL’s DC power supply instead of the AC output.